# SQlite and PHP - Console issue

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo, console

On Windows Server 2008 R2, I am trying to set up a scheduled task to automatically run a PHP script which then adjusts the SQlite database. I am using SQlite as I need to use a database file. Whenever I run the script, it returns this error:

[image]

But when I run it in the web browser, it works perfectly.

My code is:

> $db = new PDO("sqlite:server_status.db");
>       $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stats";  
$results = $db->query($sql);  

foreach($results as $row) {  
    print_r($row);  
}
```

Comment: It seams like your database does not contain table 'stats'. First create the table in sqlite database.

Comment: It exists. It displays it correctly in the web browser.

Comment: Then it seems might be a security issue. What user runs it in schedule task? Does that user have access permission to your db file?

Comment: It runs it as SYSTEM, and SYSTEM has full control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert with PDO or SQLITE but looking at your console output it seems that your current working directory is `c:/windows/system32` but that is not your web root.

Therefore PDO will be looking for your database file at: `c:/windows/system32/server_status.db` which i presume is not the correct path.

Either define your sqlite database location as a full absolute path starting with `C:\`, or change your current directory to the folder containing the sqlite database file.

Comment: Just quickly checked that and confirmed it. Thanks, I would never have figured that.